# Angular formArray inside formArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing inline editing in my project, i am trying to patchvalue data from server, i have formarray inside the formArray for my **accountNumbers** array, but when i try to change value of inputs it gives error: Error: Cannot find control with path: 'type -> options -> 0 -> accountNumbers -> accountNumber'
what am i doing wrong?
here  is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6uktzp?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.ts)

.ts

```
    this.editCompanies = this._formBuilder.group({
      type: this._formBuilder.group({
        options: this._formBuilder.array([]),
      }),
    });

    const control = <FormArray>this.editCompanies.get('type.options');
    this.items.forEach((x) => {
      control.push(
        this.patchValues(x.name, x.identificationCode, x.accountNumbers)
      );
      console.log(control);
    });
  }

  patchValues(name, identificationCode, accountNumbers) {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      name: [name],
      identificationCode: [identificationCode],
      accountNumbers: new FormArray([this.initOptions()]),
    });
  }

  initOptions() {
    return new FormGroup({
      accountNumber: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
```

.html

```
  <div class="col-lg-5 accountNumbers">
    <span formArrayName="accountNumbers">
        <span class="value" [ngClass]="{'my_class': hidemeSub[index] === true}"
        [hidden]="hidemeSub[index]"> {{item.accountNumbers}}</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accountNumber" [hidden]="!hidemeSub[index]">
    </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the path, you can see that your missing the index of the elemento of the second FormArray.

> type -> options -> 0 -> accountNumbers -> **[missing_index]** ->
> accountNumber

Similar as you are assigning the first `FormArray` index using:

```
<div class="example-accordion-item-header nusx row" formArrayName="options"
    *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="index">
```

You need also to loop through the second array items and assign this second index using the proper *Control*Name directive. Since its also an array of `FormGroup`, you could do something like this:

```
<ng-container 
  *ngFor="let accountNumber of item.accountNumbers; let accIndex = index" 
  [formGroupName]="accIndex"
>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accountNumber" [hidden]="!hidemeSub[index]">
</ng-container>
```

**EDIT**

You also need to properly initialize the `FormGroup` for the account numbers, creating one group per account:

```
patchValues(name, identificationCode, accountNumbers) {
  return this._formBuilder.group({
    ...
    accountNumbers: new FormArray(
      accountNumbers.map((account) => this.createAccountControl(account))
    ),
  });
}


//I renamed the method initOptions to better reflect the purpose
createAccountControl(initialValue: string = '') {
  return new FormGroup({
    accountNumber: new FormControl(initialValue),
  });
}
```

Cheers

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! i tried your code but accIndex is 1 for all inputs, i updated my stackblitz.

Comment: The problem is that you aren't creating one `FormGroup` per accountNumber in the array. I've updated my answer to show you how you can solve it.

Comment: thank u so much for your help and detailed answer! can i ask you one more question? as you can see i am doing inline editing, but for the object that has no accountNumbers when you click on edit input is hidden, why is that? i want user to add it if it is empty

Comment: I updated my stackblitz